# Why iPhone/iPad simulator is not launching in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I downloaded Titanium and installed. As instructed in quick guide, I created Hello World Project. I run the project. Looks everything going well. Last few line in console:

```
[INFO] : Running application in iOS Simulator 
[INFO] : Launching application in iOS Simulator 
[INFO] : Focusing the iOS Simulator [
[INFO] : Application has exited from iOS Simulator 
[INFO] : Project built successfully in 37s 420ms
```

However, the simulator doesn't launched. What went wrong?

Comment: Have you try with different Titanium SDK's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after upgrading to Mac to 10.8

Comment: Really? I mean...really? This gets better all the time.

Answer (score 1):

try to clean build project and delete app if installed in simulator then try again.

try this 3-4 times because sometimes it creates problem as you got.

and also try to build app with different titanium sdks as well.

Comment: I had to lower my api to the lowest one before it would work for me.  For those that don't know how, double-click the tiapp.xml (from in eclipse) to edit.  The API level is one of the options on that page.